# Set arrayformaula in table that refers to tables on other sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set the array formula:

`=VLOOKUP(MID([@[Source Sheet]];FIND(".";[@[Source Sheet]];1)+1;15);Tbl_PN[[Hostname]:[Allocated on:]];COLUMN(Tbl_PN[[#Headers];[Allocated on:]])-2;0)`

In a table, but I get an error:

> Runtime error 1004 Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the
>   Range class

Tbl_PN is on another sheet that the table I am trying to set an arrayformule. BTW If I copy the formula manual to the sheet then it works fine, and if I change the formula on the ".formula" line to "=-3" then the code runs fine

```
With Wb.Sheets(Sht1)
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = .Cells(StartCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set TblRange = Range(StartCell, Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))         ' set range to create new table
    Set ObjTable = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TblRange, , xlYes)      ' create new table
    ObjTable.Name = "tbl_" + Sht1                                       ' set table name
    ObjTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"                            ' set table style"
    ObjTable.ListColumns.Add.Name = "Frame"                             ' add column to table
    ObjTable.ListColumns("Frame").Range.NumberFormat = "General"        ' set format new column to general (other are text)
    ObjTable.ListColumns("Frame").DataBodyRange(1).FormulaArray = "=VLOOKUP(MID([@[Source Sheet]];FIND(""."";[@[Source Sheet]];1)+1;15);Tbl_PN[[Hostname]:[Allocated on:]];COLUMN(Tbl_PN[[#Headers];[Allocated on:]])-2;0)"
End With
```

Comment: Replace the `;` with `,`.  Formulas in vba must be in American English format.

Comment: Thanks Scott, thats the solution, The code runs fine after replacing ; with ,